# how to update a field table by linq in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a table in SQL like this, and need to transform it as follows:

**Input**

```
   A | B
  --------
   1 | al
   2 | bb
   3 | CC
```

**Output**

```
   A | B
  -------
   1 | a
   2 | b
   3 | c
```

Comment: Are you want to select these data in the Output format you posted, or *Bulk update* them to be look like the data in the Output format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General idea
correction:

```
var result = db.tables
    .Where(x => (x.B!=null || x.B.Length > 0)
    .Select(x => 
        new 
        {
           A = x.A, 
           B = x.B[0]
        });
```

Comment: Not sure that will work.  I don't think Linq-to-SQL supports IsNullOrEmpty.  Maybe not string-indexing, either.

Comment: @dbaseman You are right with Linq-To-SQL. You can alwayy use is null or length to check

Comment: @jebberwocky, Your query will select the results as the OP wants, but I think the OP is asking about how can he update the data in the table by this results, i.e bulk update these data on the condition with the new format

Answer (score 1):

```
db.table.ToList().ForEach(x => x.B = x.B.SubString(0, 1));
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this it is in SQL though, the last line is the kind of query you can use to make the transform, this can also be used in a bulk update

```
Declare @tab table(A int,B nvarchar(10))
insert into @tab
select 1,'al' UNION ALL
select 2,'bb' UNION ALL
select 3,'CC' 

select A,B from @tab

select A, left(lower(B),1) B from @tab
```